# Complexity of computing roots in general rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, computational-complexity

The Rabin Cryptosystem derives its basic security assumption on the observation, that computing roots in integer modulo $n$ rings, is as hard as finding the prime decomposition of $n$.

Mathematically this means that computing the set of all $y\in\mathbb{Z}_n$
such that $y^2=x$ for any given $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ is as complicated as finding prime numbers $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ with $n=p_1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{j_k}$

This is well understood for ages. However the question: How complicated is it (in computational complexity terms) to solve the equation

$y^2=x$,

in a ring $R$, is well defined in arbitrary (not necessarily commuative) rings and moreover in groups. Are there other examples of rings (or groups) where the complexity is well understood, too?